# Any problems having a visual studio project on Google Drive?

Tags: visual-studio, google-drive-api

I often make copies of my Visual Studio project files to Google Drive as "oh crap" backups. What if I just had the whole project on the Google drive and just worked on the project directly on the Google Drive?

Anyone try this? Any issues crop up from it?

Comment: Not really an answer so I'll make it a comment: I've tried doing this with Dropbox with fine results. Additionally, I'm now using visualstudio.com which has free TFS hosting.

Comment: I am experiencing some problems with Google Drive and Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 x64. Files with .suo extension are reported by GD as "unsyncable". Also, on a second computer pointing at the Google Drive, I have to manually sync.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR version: As long as you develop in serial it's fine. Parallel development across devices = bad.

More info:

I use it for sharing development projects between devices (Mac and various Win 10 PCs), and its a plus/minus affair overall (as of Jan 2016):

1) An integrated GIT folder seems to work perfectly fine being transferred between machines back and forth, as long as you are using only one machine at a time, commit only from one machine at a time, and use one machine as a focus.

2) Separately from GIT, using devices in parallel is bad (i.e. dev on both simultaneously for multiplayer testing & development), and leads to source files being confused and duplicated, as GD will try to sync them before work on them is done or committed (every time a file is saved). Develop only on one machine at a time.

3) Large projects have trouble syncing quickly because of the large number of small files (>1510 files changed over the course of a day or two, e.g. the OBJ folders, the Bin folders with different build configs etc.. etc.. ), so assume an increase in electricity costs keeping machines on to keep the sync up to date.

4) Executing projects also has an issue, as Google Drive will lock files for upload as VS makes them and then VS can't copy them,  the build will time out every single time. It's best to pause Google Drive when actively developing on a machine (then turn on during the 5 minute tea breaks etc..).

5) It's great for keeping Content in sync, i.e. art files (3DS MAX, Photoshop, Paint, etc..), music, textures, language files, all the stuff that's too big/impractical/problematic to use GIT for.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my personal Visual Studio Projects in Google Drive. Not for backup but for sharing between computers (PC/laptop/tablet).

This Works pretty well. The only problem i notice is when i run some Projects Visual Studio deletes some files and Google Drive keeps asking if i really want to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

Google Backup and Sync will keep syncing your bin and obj folders as you build/debug your program. This consumes unnecessary network, disk, and CPU usage. To prevent that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704427/10355922