# How to configure package.json to place node_modules in another folder outside of the web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, yarn-v2

I have a web app located under `C:\Google-drive\vue-app`. Running `yarn build` command will install node_modules folder in `C:\Google-drive\vue-app`. I am using Google Drive to sync my web app source code to Google cloud. The problem I am facing is the thousands of files in node_modules will crash Google Drive.

Is there some way to configure package.json to install node_modules folder outside of `C:\Google-drive\vue-app` and have it installed in a location called `C:\temp\node_storage`?

I am open to any solution that can stop Google Drive from syncing node_modules folder. It need not necessarily involve configuring package.json

Comment: Firstly putting the dependencies somewhere else would likely break module resolution for whatever's using them. If your question's just "how do I stop Google Drive syncing a specific folder?" I don't think that's specific to programming. But more broadly this doesn't seem like a healthy workflow - use actual version control, and deploy as a push not a pull so you can add predeployment checks (i.e. build and test _then_ deploy if successful).

Comment: Version Control Systems like git have figured this problem you are describing out years ago.  Why are you using your own method of backing up your codebase instead of using a (free) VCS that already does it better?

Comment: I use git and Dropbox/GoogleDrive at the same time. The disadvantage about git is it doesn't backup the code in real-time automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question. Not satisfactory but it works.

Use FreeFileSync application. This free app allows the user to select folders to sync to Google Drive. The user can select the source code folders to sync to Google Drive, excluding node_modules folder.

For more convenience, there is a real-time sync feature in this app. It requires some configuration. I have not tested it. If this real-time sync feature is not enabled, then manual syncing is required.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a few options suggested over at [Excluding node_modules folders from syncing with Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941682/excluding-node-modules-folders-from-syncing-with-google-drive).

Replacing node_modules with a symbolic link looks to be the simplest.

I know Dropbox has an undocumented method using an alternate file stream that can be done in Windows to avoid syncing certain folders. I use this batch script to set the alternate file stream:

```
@echo off

REM This script should be executed from the root of the repo
REM Folders which potentially can become large (node_modules, logs, etc) will be created
REM then a stream file created that instructs the Dropbox service to keep the folder locally, but not sync to the cloud
set repoRootPath=%cd%

REM Back Folders:
mkdir %repoRootPath%\back\node_modules
echo 1 > %repoRootPath%\back\node_modules:com.dropbox.ignored

mkdir %repoRootPath%\back\logs
echo 1 > %repoRootPath%\back\logs:com.dropbox.ignored
```

Comment: Dropbox has no problems syncing node_modules folder. Dropbox has superior syncing capabilities compared to Google Drive. I have experience with both.

Comment: I know Dropbox doesn't have a problem syncing the node_modules folder, but if you're cheap (like me) and only have the free version of Dropbox (with its limited storage), then you don't want to eat up your cloud space with the contents of node_modules folder (which can quickly become 100MB+), especially which it can easily be restored with `npm i`.

Comment: @guagay_wk Dropbox doesn't have any errors itself, but causes errors because it locks files so commands like `npm update` fail. In addition, because `node_modules` contains so many tiny files, it takes a very long time to sync something that doesn't need to be sync'ed.

Comment: hmm ... I didn't encounter the problems you mentioned on Dropbox. Maybe my node_modules folder wasn't large enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to configure package managers like that. The only reason I purchased Insync was so my `node_modules` folders would not be synced to cloud services like Google drive or Dropbox.

**Insync supports ignore rules:** https://www.insynchq.com/i/features/ignore-rules

> Ignore rules works like .gitignore

> Set rules for files or folders you don't want to sync.
> ... node_modules, anyone?

Insync works very well. Overall the experience is much better than having `node_modules` constantly and needlessly syncing to the cloud.

Sometimes the sync gets a little janky after removing or adding a whole bunch of files suddenly (like `npm install`). Other times git gets confused because files seem like they were modified, but they were just deleted and recreated by sync. (A simple `git add .` resolves this.)

Also at first the Insync UI can be a little confusing to get set up correctly. There are just a lot of features I don't need like two-way vs. one-way cloud sync. But once it's set up, it works automatically. So you can pretty much forget about it.

---

A bonus feature of Insync is I can move my git projects outside the folder (and even drive) limitations dictated by Google Drive/Dropbox. For example:

- My git projects are synced to `c:\dropbox\p\`
- Insync lets me work with my projects from `s:\p` (I think a bare drive like `p:` is also possible.)
- (I configure Dropbox not to sync `c:\dropbox\p\` so I only have one copy synced locally)

---

Before that, I was using this script to tell Dropbox not to sync `node_modules` folders. But it only applies to existing folders, so must be repeated if new `node_modules` folders are created:

**ignore_node_modules.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

find "$1" -type d | grep 'node_modules$' | grep -v '/node_modules/' | xargs -I {} -t powershell -command "Set-Content -Path '{}' -Stream com.dropbox.ignored -Value 1"
```

See this question for more details about the script above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655523/117030 (I used git-bash for windows, thus the mix of bash and powershell.)

Comment: Dropbox can sync node_module. It's Google Drive that's giving the problem. You don't need to pay for 3rd-party solutions if you're using Dropbox. I have used both. Dropbox is superior to Google Drive, but more expensive.